# Leer datos de tipo char hasta que el usuario presione enter

Tags: c++

Quiero leer en una linea varias letras usando un bucle y que cuando el usuario presione enter termine el bucle, pero no consigo que termine no entiendo por qué.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```cpp
char cadena;
bool check = true;

while(cin >> cadena && check == true){
    if(cadena = '\n'){
        check = false;
    }

    cout << cadena << endl;
}
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas controlar es la tecla enter del usuario, echale un ojo a este enlace: http://www.linuxhispano.net/2011/08/23/controlar-teclas-especiales-con-c-flechas-enter-tab-esc-en-entornos-windows/

Comment: @Fergush como puedo incluirlo en mi código? No encuentro la forma...

Comment: Con la función "getch()", la cual captura el código ascii asociado a la tecla que pulsa el usuario. Lo explica todo muy bien en el enlace que te facilité

Comment: A mi si me funciona tu codigo.

Answer (score 2):

> pero no consigo que termine no entiendo por qué.

No lo consigues por varias razones:

**1. Utilidad equivocada**

```
cin >> cadena
```

`cin` **jamás** te va a devolver un salto de línea usando el operador de extracción. La razón es que las salidas que te ofrecen están ya formateadas... y en ese formateo se va a perder **siempre** el salto de línea.

Para leer el salto de línea usando `cin` puedes usar el método `get`:

```
char c;
std::cin.get(c);
```

**2. Operador equivocado**

```
if(cadena = '\n')
```

Aquí se te ha olvidado el doble igual, que es lo que usamos en C++ para realizar comparaciones.

Lo que está sucediendo en tu caso es que estás asignando un salto de línea a `cadena`, con lo que su contenido previo (es decir, lo que ha leído de `cin`) se pierde.

**Sugerencias**

Nota que no es necesario, reevaluar si un booleano es `true`. Una variable de tipo `bool` se puede evaluar tal cual. Dicho con un ejemplo, estas dos líneas serían equivalentes:

```
if( flag == true )
if( flag )
```

Por otro lado, intenta evitar el uso de `std::endl`. La razón es que fuerza el vaciado del buffer de salida... y el buffer está ahí por algo. Si lo vacías a cada caracter que le metes tendrás una importante penalización en el rendimiento de la aplicación (en este caso no se nota, pero en casos más complejos sí).

Piensa que en C++ el buffer de salida se vacía automáticamente bajo ciertas circunstancias:

- Realizas una lectura de `cin`
- El buffer se llena
- El programa finaliza
- ...

Puedes añadir saltos de línea sin forzar al vaciado del buffer usando `\n`.

**Solución**

Tu código, corregido, podría quedar así:

```
char cadena;
bool check = true;

while(cin.get(cadena) && check)
{
    if(cadena == '\n'){
        check = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // No querrás sacar el salto de línea, ¿verdad?
        cout << cadena << '\n';
    }
}
```

O, simplificando aun más:

```
char cadena;
bool check = true;

while(cin.get(cadena) && check)
{
    if( check = (cadena != '\n') )
    {
        cout << cadena << '\n';
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, tal y como te comentan en la otra respuesta, para leer líneas en C++ puedes usar la función `std::getline`. Esta función realiza el esfuerzo por ti y te devuelve la cadena cómodamente empaquetada en un objeto de tipo `std::string`.

No te pongo una solución usando `std::getline` porque ya tienes una respuesta donde se detalla.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puedes optar por la alternativa de *@Fergush* aunque si lo que realmente quieres es leer una línea puedes usar la función `getline` mira un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main (){
  string line;
  getline (cin, line);
  cout << "Línea escaneada:\"" << line << "\"\n";
  return 0;
}
```